# pyephem FixedObject() for given RA/Dec

Tags: python, pyephem

I'm looking to determine the alt/az of (un-famous) stars at given RA/Dec at specific times from Mauna Kea. I'm trying to compute these parameters using pyephem, but the resulting alt/az don't agree with other sources. Here's the calculation for HAT-P-32 from Keck:

```
import ephem
telescope = ephem.Observer()
telescope.lat =  '19.8210'
telescope.long = '-155.4683'
telescope.elevation = 4154
telescope.date = '2013/1/18 10:04:14'
star = ephem.FixedBody()
star._ra = ephem.degrees('02:04:10.278')
star._dec = ephem.degrees('+46:41:16.21')
star.compute(telescope)
print star.alt, star.az
```

which returns `-28:43:54.0 73:22:55.3`, though according to Stellarium, the proper alt/az should be: `62:26:03 349:15:13`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Corrected latitude and longitude, which were formerly reversed.

Comment: Random note: if you are trying to view HAT-P-32, then I think the right ascension is `02:01:10`, not `02:04:10`? Or are you looking at another object in that vicinity and so your right ascension is correct after all?

Comment: I'm talking about HAT-P-32, I got the RA/dec from [SIMBAD](http://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-id?Ident=hat-p-32&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id). Sub-arcminute precision isn't necessary for the calculations that I'm looking to do anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyEphem always uses UTC for time, so that programs operate the same and give the same output wherever they are run. You simply need to convert the date you are using to UTC, instead of using your local time zone, and the results agree fairly closely with Stellarium; use:

```
telescope.date = '2013/1/18 05:04:14'
```

The result is this alt/az:

```
62:27:19.0 349:26:19.4
```

To know where the small remaining difference comes from, I would have to look into how the two programs handle each step of their computation; but does this get you close enough?

Comment: Yes, thanks Brandon! I guess Stellarium uses the system time's time zone?

Comment: Yes, when I installed and ran Stellarium, it used my system's time zone (and not, as I had at first expected, the time zone of the observatory you choose as the observation point!).

Answer (score 1):

First, you've got long and latitude backwards; second, you need to provide the strings in hexadecimal form; and third, you need to provide the RA as hours, not degrees:

```
import ephem
telescope = ephem.Observer()
# Reversed longitude and latitude for Mauna Kea
telescope.lat =    '19:49:28' # from Wikipedia
telescope.long = '-155:28:24'
telescope.elevation = 4154.
telescope.date = '2013/1/18 00:04:14'
star = ephem.FixedBody()
star._ra  = ephem.hours('02:04:10.278') # in hours for RA
star._dec = ephem.degrees('+46:41:16.21')
star.compute(telescope)
```

This way, you get:

```
>>> print star.alt, star.az
29:11:57.2 46:43:19.6
```

Comment: I've changed some of the parameters in the original post before you answered (note the time was changed to indicate UT). I'm getting the same result as you now, which still does not agree with Stellarium. Is it possible that Stellarium is completely wrong?

Comment: I doubt Stellarium is wrong (but it might!). I know PyEphem is not wrong because I've double checked for other projects with IDL code and algorithms from NOAO. I would suspect the setup of the site in Stellarium, have you tested that?

Comment: The Stellarium "Keck Observatory" preset seems to be accurate enough in terms of lat/long and elevation.

Comment: The `lat` and `long` do not *have* to be in sexagesimal form — I think, if you will check the way @BrettMorris is setting them with decimal numbers, you will find that it stores the correct value.

Comment: Also: note that your sample code here changes the time from `10:04:14` to `00:04:14` which of course makes a large difference in the result :)

Comment: Oh, the time zone of Hawaii is 10 hours off UTC. Is that why you were adjusting his time by 10 hours?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was adjusting it.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes: Yeap, you're right, I was distracted first by the weird results I was having when `lat` and `long` where switched.